# Find if a program is installed on remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to connect to remote computers with Active Directory and see if a single program is installed. I have tried a couple tutorials I found on the Internet, but with no success:

- http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/what-applications-are-installed-computers-your-network
- http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2170-get-a-list-of-installed-software-from-a-remote-computer-fast-as-lightning

I cannot get them to work properly, and they are not exactly what I am looking for.

An example of what I want to do: say I have 3 computers on my network:

```
123-abc
123-bcd
123-cde
```

and I want to see if the executable `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe` exists. Can someone please explain how I can go about this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, provided you have domain admin privileges and administrative shares are enabled and accessible on the target computers, would be this:

```psh
$computers = '123-abc', '123-bcd', '123-cde'
$path = 'C$\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe'

$computers | % {
  '{0}: {1}' -f $_, (Test-Path -LiteralPath "\\$_\$path")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of ways to check for installed software. Some better suited than others. But if you're certain on the file path on each machine, the Test-Path CmdLet could be an easy approach.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 123-abc -ScriptBlock {Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe'}
```

You could probably throw that into a loop with a custom object so you can work with it as well.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting the error `OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException` and I'm not sure what it means. I googled it a couple times, but the results are not very helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For example, your code could look like this.

```
$pass = "password";
$secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force;
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("domain\login", $secpass);
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 123-abc, 123-bcd, 123-cde -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {
    Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"
};
```

There are multiple ways of running powershell commands on remote computers.

- Many commands support `string[]` parameter `-ComputerName` to which you can pass multiple computer names
- You can use the `Enter-PSSession` cmdlet to enter a Telnet-like session on the remote machine
- And finally, you can use the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet to run a script block against multiple remote hosts.

Comment: I am actually trying to bulk test a bunch of machines, and I dont have the password for all of them, but I have access to ActiveDirectory. Is there any way to implement AD into this?

Comment: Well, I'm not so good at AD stuff, but at least you can't pull someone's password out of it, it uses irreversible encryption. Just to think of it, if having access to ActiveDirectory would allow you to so simply use someone's identity - it would compromise the security. Anyway, it's another issue, and maybe someone knows some esoteric way to do what you want. I'd be glad to know )